# I have trouble making a ruby file

Tags: files, ruby

I try to make a file but it said 'The file is not valid.'

```
    require "./lib/NAME.rb"
    require "test/unit"

    class TestNAME < Test::Unit::TestCase

      def test_sample
        assert_equal(4, 2+2)
      end

    end
```

The other files in my folders are all good but when it comes to this file it doesn't work. any answers are fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I tried, that code works just fine.

```
require "test/unit"

class TestNAME < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_sample
    assert_equal(4, 2+2)
  end

end

# Running tests:

Finished tests in 0.007099s, 140.8649 tests/s, 140.8649 assertions/s.
1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

ruby -v: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0]
```

I guess there is something wrong in `./lib/NAME.rb` file.

Can you paste it here?